# Tor with curl and php - "Can't complete SOCKS5 connection to 0.0.0.0:0"

Tags: php, curl, tor

I am using Vidalia Bridge software with curl and PHP to scrape some websites. There's this website that somehow manages to give me "Can't complete SOCKS5 connection to 0.0.0.0:0" each time I have 11 or more concurrent requests.
3 weeks ago when I last tested it, it used to be 31 or more requests until I got the error message from above, now it's 11.

Edit:
Here is a diagram explaining what's mine (can control) and what's remote (can't control) and the full relationships between the components.

[image: Click for diagram]

My question is:
Is this something related to the website(could they control the number of requests per second, considering I am using a different cookie file for each request), or is it something related to vidalia/curl settings.

Edit: Here is my configuration:
I'm using Java with multiple threads, each thread is accessing a local PHP script that has the role of scraping a website given as a GET parameter. The PHP script uses CURL with 9050 as a port to TOR(Vidalia Bridge) in order to scrape .onion websites.

Edit 2: (More details)
I'm using:
a) XAMPP for windows:

b) Vidalia Bridge Bundle:

Here is the code in PHP: ( curlSample.php )

```
<?php
        $ch = curl_init();
        /*
        ********************************
        Comment or uncomment below
        */

        $url="http://alphabaywyjrktqn.onion/";
        //$url="http://nucleuspf3izq7o6.onion/";

        /*
        Comment or uncomment above
        ********************************
        */


        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        // Set Vidalia Bridge (Tor proxy socks connection)
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "http://127.0.0.1:9050");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 7);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        $curl_error = curl_error($ch);
        if(strlen($curl_error) > 0){
            echo $curl_error;
            exit();
        }
        echo $output;
```

Here is the code in Java:
a) AlphaTestConnections.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class AlphaTestConnections {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int start=0;
        int end=20;
        ArrayList<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
        for(int i=start; i<end; i++){
            threads.add(new Thread(new AlphaTestConnectionsThread(i)));
        }
        for(int i=0; i<threads.size(); i++){
            threads.get(i).start();
        }
        for(int i=0; i<threads.size(); i++){
            try {
                threads.get(i).join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("done");
    }
}
```

b) AlphaTestConnectionsThread.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class AlphaTestConnectionsThread implements Runnable{

    private final static String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
    private static String request() {
        try{
            URL obj = new URL("http://localhost/curlSample.php");
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

            // optional default is GET
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");

            //add request header
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);


            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }

            in.close();

            // Return first 50 characters from source code (enough to test this)
            return response.toString().substring(0, 50);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

    private int i;
    public AlphaTestConnectionsThread(int i){
        this.i=i;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {

        System.out.println("Thread #" + i + ": " + request());

    }
}
```

To test the code, you'll first need to start Apache in Xampp, then start the Vidalia Bridge bundle,

[image: Start Vidalia Bridge]

create the curlSample.php file in the root directory of Xampp, then run AlphaTestConnections.java.
You will see that for 20 connections, 10 will return the source code, and 10 will give you the error "Can't complete SOCKS5 connection to 0.0.0.0:0".
Now, edit curlSample.php and comment/uncomment the code to use the second URL. It will now return the source code for all 20 connections, without giving any error.
I'd like to know how is this possible, why is there a 10 concurrent connections limitation for a particular website, and how could I remove it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Every web server is different but the short answer is Yes, the web server can have limits. Apache, has MaxClients: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mpm_common.html#maxclients So I would avoid multiple concurrent connections. Also it might hit DoS like triggers for smarter systems. Then you're blocked and your fun is over.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Twisty, but here is why I think this couldn't be because of maxclients: It works just fine with other websites, it's just this particular website that gets this 10 concurrent requests limit. The website has DDos protection and sometimes the CURL response returns a DDos triggered type of web page. This is not an issue, since I can handle these types of responses too. And one more thing: When I use 2 computers on the same network using the same configuration to scrape this website, it works just fine with 10 requests on each computer. (20 in total).

Comment: It's only when I use 11 concurrent requests on ONE COMPUTER that I get the  "Can't complete SOCKS5 connection to 0.0.0.0:0" for the 11'th request. So it's one of the following, I think: 1) Apache limits the concurrent requests for this particular website only to 10. or 2) The web server (of the website) can somehow detect those requests through Vidalia (TOR) are coming from the same computer and not providing a response when there are 10 or more.

Comment: Since this number(10) used to be 30 I would think it's option 2, but also from what I understand, the website's web server has no idea of the IP address that makes the request, so how could it know they come from the same computer. (different cookie files are used, so it couldn't be because of cookies).

Comment: Option 1 is MaxClients, and I suspect it is set to 10 for that server. There is no evidence that it would be option 2.

Comment: Hi Twisty, I don't think it's option 1 because it works fine for other websites. Or is it possible to have multiple MaxClients settings for different websites? also, I've edited the post so you can test out what I mean. Please do so if you find the time. (about 10 minutes) Thank you anyway for your cooperation so far.

Comment: Yep. The default value is often 10 yet most admins will configure the server to meet the needs of that system. As I said up front, every web server is different. Of course after 20 years of working with computers, the last 8 working at a web hosting company, I am sure I know very little about this topic.

Comment: If you don't believe me, you can read the link I attached: *The MaxClients directive sets the limit on the number of simultaneous requests that will be served. Any connection attempts over the MaxClients limit will normally be queued, up to a number based on the ListenBacklog directive. Once a child process is freed at the end of a different request, the connection will then be serviced.*

Comment: <IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    ServerLimit          40
    StartServers          2
    MaxClients          1000
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>  It seems to be 1000, so it's not MaxClients

Comment: You never mentioned that it was your server. Your post made it sound like you were collecting data from remote servers. What do your Apache Error Logs say when this happens? Do you have any other modules that might restrict the number of connections from a single IP?

Comment: No, I do not have any other modules. Run the java program I've posted and you'll see it does exactly the same thing on your system too. Yes, it's my server, I use a php script that uses curl and scrapes .onion websites. The java program it's there only for requesting concurrently my local PHP script. 
These are the logs I get from curl when I get the error:
`* Hostname 127.0.0.1 was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Can't complete SOCKS5 connection to 0.0.0.0:0. (5)
* Closing connection 0`

Comment: When there is no error, this is what I get (verbose):
`* Hostname 127.0.0.1 was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 9050 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: alphabaywyjrktqn.onion
Accept: */*`

Comment: Confused now, do you host alphabaywyjrktqn.onion ? or are you running a script locally that is connecting to a remote site via curl?

Comment: I am running a script locally that is connecting to remote sites via curl, using TOR(Vidalia bridge bundle)

Comment: To clarify what I was saying earlier about MaxClients, if you do not own the target server, there is no way to know what that servers MaxClient setting is configured to. Are you only able to establish 10 connections to the remote or 10 connections to your own server?

Comment: That website has 200k+ members, there are a lot more than 10 concurrent connections to their server each second. Moreover, as I've already mentioned, if I use 2 computers and run the connections at the same time, I can get 10 on each without getting the error, or 30 with 3 computers and so on, I can't get more than 10 connections to that website on the same computer. Why is that?

Comment: It's possible they are limiting the number of sockets the server will allow for for a single session. I'm assuming your test computers are NAT'd behind the same IP? If so, this would suggest they are looking at something else in the headers and not the IP itself. Could try creating a unique UserAgent for each connection and see if that tricks it into allow more connections.

Comment: @George I've removed your call-out and monetary offer from the question; those things are not okay here.  Your question, at the time it was closed, was unclear; the solution is not to add a call-out, but to make it clear.  As to the monetary reward, that isn't acceptable here; if you need to hire a developer, SO is not the place to do so.

Comment: @Daedalus, "Your question, at the time it was closed, was unclear".
Ok, why is it still "unclear" (on hold now)? I've added details so everyone can see for themselves the issue that needs to be solved.
Why is my question still on hold?

Comment: @George Because close-voters aren't pinged when a question is edited.  When a question that was put on hold, is edited, it re-enters the reopen queue.  Once in the queue, others with the ability to re-open review the question, and either vote to re-open it, or leave it closed.

Comment: @George I can't speak for the choices others have made.  I'll review your question again, and if it meets the needed requirements, I'll add a reopen vote.

Comment: @George I still believe your question is unclear; a few times in the comments above, as well as the question, you've made it sound like you either control the sites you are attempting to scrape, or that you do not.  Please be clear here.

Comment: @Daedalus , I've read the description and comments and I see the confusion I've been conveying so I've edited the description with this diagram. Hope this will clear everything out. 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/dhk5r.jpg
And I am sorry for the call-out, I wasn't aware of the rules.

Comment: @George Thank you for the clarification; I've cast my re-open vote.

Comment: @Daedalus , Thank you for casting your re-open vote. The description seemed obvious until I read it from another perspective. I really hope I can finally get passed this. It's been like 4 days since I'm stuck already. It would help me if someone with your experience and expertise would try to tackle this issue.

Comment: I've looked at headers as @Twisty suggested but I can't see nothing fishy there. I've tried loading _curlSample.php_, on about 30 tabs and used ReloadAllTabs extention to simulate 30 threads. It works fine this way, all 30 tabs return the scraped webpage, but then again, maybe the tabs in Chrome are not truly concurrently managed after all.
It really perplexes me since all they can see is 127.0.0.1 as the IP for all requests ( due to the TOR protocol ), and still they manage to limit me to 10 concurrent connections. Or maybe it's from my local configuration. That's what I'm trying to find out.

Comment: @George based on the the testing and that this works on other sites, I feel confident that something on the remote server is throttling or limiting the number of connections in some way. I would investigate the various things you can set in curl. Also look at how TOR is handling this. There might be something that is being caught there. When you tested with Chrome, did each of the tab sessions go through TOR? Did you use flags to isolate each tab?